# Default activity not found - Nothing solves this problem

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-manifest

I can't find the default activity when running my new app, I also can't find what's the issue in my manifests. I tried to read a lot about this but nothing of those similar problems seemed to help me out.

This is what my manifests look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.pear.game">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/minionicon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/minionicon"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT: // LOGIN CLASS

I tried to Invalidate caches/restart, but that didn't work.
So, here comes the login class and I hope we can found a solution for this error together.

```
package com.example.pear.game
    import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*
import java.util.*

class Login : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mAuth:FirebaseAuth?=null

    private var database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    private var myRef=database.reference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    }

    fun buLoginEvent(view:View){

        LoginToFirebase(etUser.text.toString(),etPassword.text.toString())
    }

    fun LoginToFirebase(email:String,password:String){

        mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this){task ->

                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Successful login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    var currentUser=mAuth!!.currentUser
                    // Save in database
                    if(currentUser!=null) {
                        myRef.child("Users").child(SplitString(currentUser.email.toString())).child("Request")
                            .setValue(currentUser.uid).toString()
                    }
                    LoadMain()

                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        LoadMain()
    }

    fun LoadMain(){
        var currentUser=mAuth!!.currentUser

        if(currentUser!=null) {
            var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("email", currentUser.email)
            intent.putExtra("uid", currentUser.uid)

            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
fun SplitString(str:String):String{
    var splitStr=str.split('@')
    return splitStr[0]
}
```

Comment: Could you post code of `Login` class

Comment: Please read [this meta post on swearing in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites). Also, create a [mcve]

Comment: I wouldn't consider damn a swear word.

Comment: Could you share your Login class? It could be a typo in your activity name or different package name..

Comment: Yes I just shared it in the main post now.

Answer (score 0):

This error is for the IDE, try replace this:

```
    <activity android:name=".Login">
```

For this:

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.pear.game.Login">
```

Comment: I tried this aswell but it didn't fix the error. Could it be anything outside the manifest folder causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to invalide caches from File -> Invalide Caches/ Restart and from the same menu sync project wit Gradle files.

And it may be a stupid question but important, does this activity extend `AppCompatActivity`? If not that's why it's not visible in manifest

Comment: Yes it extend AppCompatActivity. Ok, do you know how to fix the error?

Comment: OK, so to sum up, manifest doesn't find activity or is there an error while installing? Could you provide more informations or attach a screenshot of the problem with logs?

Comment: Manifest dont find Default activity, that's it I think. So the program not even run, only "Error running 'app': Default Activity not found" appears in left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Click `Run/Edit Configurations...` 
select `app` and in `General` tab 
under `Launch Options` make sure that 
in `Launch:` the selected option is  
`Default Activity`